# Photo capture / screen shot with mouse click

Tags: windows-7, security, screenshot, webcam

I am looking for software that will take a photo via webcam and screen shot when someone clicks the mouse anywhere on the screen. The software should run on Windows-7 64bit.

It will be used for a clock-in/clock-out computer in a plant. It is suppose to monitor employees because all they're suppose to do is clock in and out. So I would need to see who is using the computer, and what they're doing, if they decide to stray off onto the internet or into the system.

Answer (score 3):

I made my own simple program through AutoIt, [you can download it here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03196541240812024787).

Each time the left mouse button is clicked, it will take a snapshot of the screen and if there is a camera on your computer, it takes a snapshot using the camera.

The captures are placed in C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Captures
You can stop the program by holding the control key and s.

Here is the code,

```
#NoTrayIcon
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
DirCreate(@AppDataDir & "/Captures/")
$directory = @AppDataDir & "\Captures\"
Local $hDLL = DllOpen("user32.dll")
While 1
    If _IsPressed("01", $hDLL) Then
        Example()
    EndIf
    If _IsPressed("11") And _IsPressed("53") Then
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
WEnd
Func Example()
    $time = @YEAR & "-" & @MON & "-" & @MDAY & "-" & @HOUR & "-" & @MIN & "-" & @SEC & "-" & @MSEC
    _ScreenCapture_Capture($directory & "Capture_" & $time & "_Window.jpg")
    Run("snapz.exe" & ' dir /b', $directory, @SW_HIDE)
    _FileRename_($directory & "snapz.dib", $directory & "Capture_" & $time & "_CameraSnapShot.dib")
EndFunc   ;==>Example

Func _FileRename_($s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag = 0)
    Local $i
    $i = FileMove($s_Source, $s_Destination, $i_Flag)
    Return $i
EndFunc   ;==>_FileRename_
```

I used a simple script called ["snapz"](http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/snapz-a-command-line-cam-image-grabber/) to get the camera snapshots.

Hope this helps, if you have any questions, ask away:)